# Good resources for learning JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone suggest good learning materials or websites to learn JavaScript and jQuery? Am pretty new to this and want to learn right from basics.

Thanks in advance,
Geetha

Comment: Possible duplicate? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Javascript: The Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748/) by Douglas Crockford is a really good and thorough book about Javascript. Once you speak Javascript you don't really have to *learn* jQuery, you can just *use* it.

Comment: +1 for "use jQuery, not learn it". This is something which works for most libraries in most languages. Don't try t learn it, but use what you need when you need it.

Comment: I'm not sure this book is that good for absolute beginners. It's OK though after you grasped the basics, or maybe for reading it in parallel with a beginner's tutorial.

Answer (score 6):

My recommended reading list

**JavaScript**

- [JavaScript - the Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101996)
- [Pro JavaScript Techniques](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590597273)
- [JavaScript - the Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)
- [Object Oriented JavaScript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847194141)
- [Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja](http://www.manning.com/resig/)

**jQuery**

- [jQuery in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988355)
- [Learning jQuery 1.3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847196705)

I also recommend [JSBin](http://jsbin.com) for testing and trying out ideas

The following sites are also useful

**JavaScript**

- [Mozilla JavaScript Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript)
- [Dean Edward's blog](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/)
- [Remy Sharp's b:log](http://remysharp.com/tag/javascript/)
- [Ajaxian](http://ajaxian.com/by/topic/javascript)

**jQuery**

- [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Core)
- [jQuery for designers](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/)
- [Learning jQuery](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/)
- [Brandon Aaron's blog](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/)

Answer (score 2):

[A re-introduction to JavaScript by Simon Willison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript) is a very concise overview of the language, yet it offers you a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

If you're already a programmer, [Pro Javascript Techniques](http://jspro.org/) by John Resig was a good book for having that "aha" moment with javascript - it finally started to make sense.  Surprisingly enough, even though it's written by the creator of jQuery - it really doesn't cover it at all.  Although you will gain a deeper understanding of how to write good Object Oriented stuff using javascript.

Answer (score 2):

I have learnt from the first one

**[maconstateit](http://www.maconstateit.net/tutorials/JSDHTML/default.htm)** Tuts on Javascript

EDIT: [SoftLookup](http://www.softlookup.com/tutorial/JavaScript/index.asp)

```
  http://www.javascriptmall.com/learn/

  http://jennifermadden.com
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to learn what's behind JavaScript you can go hardcore and dive into the specification:

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm

Comment: -1. Specs are for researching problems, not for a beginner to learn from.

Answer (score 0):

There are NOW some good interactive tutorials for learning Javascript right from the beginning. If you are fairly new to Computer Programming, try [Code Avengers](http://codeavengers.com) (a site I helped create) or [CodeCademy](http://codecademy.com). Both are free and get you to write code right from the beginning.

If you have a some programming experience, try [Code School](http://codeschool.com). It has courses for html, css, Javascript and JQuery. However, they do cost about $50 a course. Learners watch fairly entertaining video tutorials then complete programming tasks.

My experience in learning and teaching others to program is that these type of sites can be both and effective and enjoyable way to learn programming. Probably in conjunction with other resources.

Answer (score -1):

http://w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Excellent resource. Completely free.

Comment: It has been mentioned in earlier answers, and it isn't excellent, it is littered with errors.